# Average value of $f(x)= x\cos(x)$ on $\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Does there exist point $\xi \in[0,1]$, so that $f(\xi)=p$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have already calculated average value $p$, using formula:
$p = \frac{(1)}{(b-a)} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)$ 
$p = \frac{2}{\pi}(x\sin(x) + \cos(x))\Bigr|_0^\frac{\pi}{2}$ 
$p = 1 - \frac{\pi}{2}$ 
What I am having trouble with is $f(\xi) = p$. I was thinking: 
\begin{align} 
p &= f(ξ)\\
1 - \frac{\pi}{2}&= 1\bigl(\xi\sin(\xi) + \cos(\xi)\bigr)\Bigr|_0^1\\
1 - \frac{\pi}{2}&= \sin(1) + \cos(1) - 1
\end{align}
but I'm not sure if that's even right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can the value of $p$ be negative, whereas the function is everywhere non-negative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of $p$ is incorrect.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x \cos(x) dx = \left[ x \sin(x) \right]_0^{\pi/2} - \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)dx  = \frac{\pi}{2} - 1$$

so $$p = \frac{2}{\pi} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - 1\right) = 1 - \frac{2}{\pi}$$

Now,
$$f(0)=0 < p \quad \text{and} \quad f(1) = \cos(1) > p$$

so by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $\xi \in [0,1]$ such that $f(\xi)=p$.